# Visual Basic 2008 'tests'

Tags: vb.net

Are there any sites which a similar program or web-exam?

The best example I can give is Auto-it's "Auto-it 1,2,3" found [here](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=21048).

This is for an absolute-beginner, myself, so even the simplest questions are going to be helpful.

Comment: In general on SO, it's best to make a question complete without the need to refer to another site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this one: **[VB.NET Quiz](http://www.ex-designz.net/test_page.asp?tid=44)**